# перепись с Питона на Си

Tags: python, c

Пожалуйста, помогите разогнать код или перевести код из Питона в Си:

```
numbers = [x, y, z, t]
for a in range(-1000, 1001):
    for b in range(-1000, 1001):
        for c in range(-1000, 1001):
            if a + b in numbers:
                numbers.remove(a+b)
                if a + c in numbers:
                    numbers.remove(a + c)
                    if b + c in numbers:
                        numbers.remove(b + c)
                        if a + b + c in numbers:
                            print(f'a = {a} | b = {b} | c = {c} ')
            numbers = [x, y, z, t]
```

проблема в том, что рэндж будет больше для работы с большими числами, но питон это слишком долго обрабатывает, поэтому я подумал, что проще будет все переделать в Си, но я не знаю Си, поэтому прошу о помощи...

Comment: Конечно поможем. Показывайте свой вариант перевода, посмотрим, подправим. Вы же просите вам "помочь", а не "написать вместо вас", правда?

Comment: к сожалению, второй вариант...
конечно, есть вариант чтобы мне "помогли" с реализацией кода на большие числа, но кажется это будет очень долго, но, если у вас есть варианты, пожалуйста, напишите!

Comment: Этот код даже на Си будет тормозить, потому что перебирать 8 миллиардов итераций в циклах — задача весьма непростая. А если range увеличивать, то даже на Си вы вряд ли дождётесь завершения его выполнения

Comment: и что же тогда делать?

Comment: читать мой ответ:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

если посмотреть на циклы, то тут перебирать много-много. очень много. Но давайте посмотрим внимательней. Очевидно, что `a+b` должно быть одним с 4 заданных чисел. Аналогично и с `a+c`. А это значит, что если зафиксировать `a`, то значения `b` и `с` входят в небольшой массив на 4 элемента. Всего то. А это сокращает время перебора в `250000` раз! Я не сильно переделывал код, совсем минимально.

```
numbers = [x, y, z, t]
for a in range(-1000, 1001):
    # это наш новый массив вариантов
    nr = [q - a for q in numbers]
    for b in nr: # и теперь бежим по маленькому списку
        for c in nr:  # аналоично
            if a + b in numbers: # вообще то это условие уже истинно, но мне лень
                numbers.remove(a+b)
                if a + c in numbers: # и это, но что если используем один вариант?
                    numbers.remove(a + c)
                    if b + c in numbers: # а это точно нужно проверить
                        numbers.remove(b + c)
                        if a + b + c in numbers: # надо было бы и это обыграть
                            print(f'a = {a} | b = {b} | c = {c} ')
            numbers = [x, y, z, t]
```

да, у этого кода есть одна маленькая проблема - в массиве `nr` могут быть числа, которые выходят за диапазон `[-1000, 1000]`, но пусть это будет домашним заданием.

у меня этот код отрабатывает за доли секунды. Я увеличил диапазон до `[-10000,10001]` (в 100 раз!) и считало за 2 с половиной секунды на очень стареньком процессоре.

Comment: мне не хватило считанных секунд, чтобы воспользоваться той инфой которую вы мне выдали, но в любом случае, большое вам спасибо!

Comment: О, анонимный минусатор с отпуска вернулся.